# Clean url without php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I used .htaccess to remove the file extensions on my webpage. I have deleted htaccess on my root folder on my website but a url like www.mywebsite.com/dashboard rewrites to www.mywebsite.com/dashboard.php

Is there anyway that the web server has cached the .htaccess file?

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Answer (score 1):

No it is because of [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html):

```
Options MultiViews
```

Try adding this line in your `.htaccess` to stop this behavior:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: The thing is it still works even after I delete the .htaccess from my web root

Comment: True I understand. This option is enabled via Apache config so it doesn't matter if your `.htaccess` is deleted. To disable that you can have line as `Options -MultiViews`